# Object move along the path

Tags: objective-c

In Objective-C, how can I move an object along a straight line or a curve? When the user presses a button, a UIImageView must move along a path. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`CAKeyframeAnimation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAKeyframeAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) on the view's layer.